# Hover state does not work when applying z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is I have 2 divs: one container a link and another a box shaped container. The link has a `position:fixed;` and it flies over the container div, so I tried to give the link a z-index with a negative value, turns out the 
hover state does not work when applying z-index with a negative value for the anchor **Unless** I scroll the same amount of the height of the container div. So I scroll like 3 times and the hover state works again.

**HTML**

```
<div id="div-1">
 <div class="container"></div>
</div>

<!-- other divs like 5 or 6 of 'em -->

<div id="div-2">
 <a href="#">This is a link</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div-2 a{
width:13%;
height:auto;
padding:0.5em 2.3em;
display:block;
position:fixed;
font-weight:500;
font-size:1.09em;
text-align: center;
background-color: none;
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
z-index:0;
}

#div-1{
width:100%;
height:290px;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
 }
```

an important thing is:
The container is hidden by Jquery, unless I click a certain button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".container").hide();
$("#button-f").click(function(e){
$(".container").toggle();
    var target = $(e.target);
if (!target.is("##button-f")) {
  $(".container").toggle();
}
});
});
```

[image: this is an illustrative image have a look]

I have resorted to every possible (other ideas) I could think of. I tried to do the opposite  meaning giving the container a z-index positive vales and leave the anchor, but that leaves the same problem

***update***
I will try to change the css property "z-index"but only when the the container button is toggled on

so the link will have `z-index:-9;` but only when the container is toggled to be viewed and when it is toggled back off the z-index will be removed or not applied.
I can't really figure how this will be written with jquery I tried this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$(".container").hide();
$("#button-f").click(function(e){
$(".container").toggle(); 

$("#div-2 a").css("z-index", -9); 

    var target = $(e.target);
if (!target.is("##button-f")) {
  $(".container").toggle();
}
});
});
```

this only result when I toggled the container on the z-index will be applied, but when i toggle it of it remains, how to remove the z-index or make it equal to `z-inedx:99;` when the container is toggled off?

Only any other answer for the problem is appreciated.

Comment: I can't follow what's going on here after reading the first long sentence. Can you post a fiddle recreating the issue?

Comment: What are you expecting? When an element is hidden underneath another element, the mouse/pointer events will only apply to the one above it, unless `pointer-events: none` is set to the overlying element(s).

Comment: @Terry The container is hidden by Jquery, unless I click a certain button.

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/u7sswczz/1/ ] can you explain? I make a fiddle for you. where I need to scroll .. Please make a fiddle with the correct code and attached with your question

Comment: An element with `position: fixed` is taken out of flow and will be positioned relative to the browser window/viewport. Also, the div's need a position, like `position: relative`, have you tried that?

Comment: @AndrewMk you need to provide code that replicates the problem. Looks like you have omitted vital CSS, HTML and JS. For example, your JS will immediately hide all elements with the class `.container` when the DOM has loaded, yet you mention when you _"click a certain button"_ they will be hidden.

Comment: @hungerstar I just removed any non-relevant code like other divs that lies between the container and the link those has nothing to do with the problem by any way , the only thing is the toggle and I will add it

Comment: @MostafaBaezid I can't create my own JS fiddle account each time I try the form for signing up is broken somehow

Comment: @LGSon I know that happens, but i need that element to stay in its fixed position, however the user scrolls the page

Comment: What's the css for div-1 and container?

Comment: @AndrewMk *"I can't create my own JSfiddle account each time I try the form for signing up is broken somehow"* Ok, there's [Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), [CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/) or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: @AndrewMk see my answer, it's div-1 100% width that was your problem.

Comment: @AndrewMk you really should cache element references instead of querying for them every time you need them. Instead of using `$( '.container' )` repeatedly, do this: `var $container = $( '.container' ); $container.toggle(); $container.click(); ` etc.

Comment: @hungerstar Thank you I will keep this tip in my head. If you have any other advice regarding my code that would enhance, please point that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you want exactly, but the pics helped, although it appears that you want the link above the container, it looks as if you don't?

> the whole purpose is to make the anchor in a lower index, so when the container is toggled on/ viewed, the link won't be setting on top of the container.

**But** you want the link to always react when hovered upon. So I assume that you can't figure out why it's not hovering when the container is open and you can still see the link, so logically you'd expect to at least be able to hover over the visible portion of the link.

1. It's not jQuery and it's not the `.container`. It's the `.container`'s container A.K.A. `#div-1`. `#div-1` width is always 100% and even if you didn't have that style, it would be 100% still because that's what blocks have if there isn't an explicit width assigned to it.

   - **Solution:** Give `#div-1` a smaller width.
2. You have a fixed link yet no coords. You can't expect a fixed element to stand it's ground and behave like a fixed element if it doesn't know where to stand. Also if you have any `positioned` elements and you want interaction between other elements, make those elements positioned as well, `div-1` is now `position:relative` and the `z-index` properties of the link and `div-1` function correctly now.

   - **Solution:** Give `#div-2 a` `top` and `left` or `right` and `bottom` properties. Give `#div-1` a `position` property so that the `z-index` functions properly.

All details are commented in the source.

[<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/mxcJN8vu95HDvTtLL4XR/)

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #div-1 {
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 200px;
      /*Enable this and it will block link*/
      /*width:100%;*/
      height: 290px;
    }
    .container {
      /* This saves you an unnecessary step in jQuery */
      display: none;
      width: 200px;
      height: 290px;
      background: orange;
    }
    #div-2 a {
      width: 13%;
      height: auto;
      padding: 0.5em 2.3em;
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 1.09em;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: none;
      /* It's not clear whether you want the link above or
      | below the container. If above, simply change to
      | z-index: 2
      */
      z-index: 0;
      /* If you have a fixed element give it coords, otherwise       
      | it doesn't know where it should stand and behavior
      | will be unexpected.
      */
      top: 10%;
      left: 125px;
    }
    #div-2 a:hover {
      background: red;
      color: white;
    }
    /* FLAG is just to test the accessibility of the link */
    #FLAG {
      display: none;
    }
    #FLAG:target {
      display: block;
      font-size: 48px;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='button-f'>F</button>
  <div id="div-1">
    <div class="container">Container is open</div>
  </div>

  <!-- other divs like 5 or 6 of 'em -->

  <div id="div-2">
    <a href="#FLAG">This is a link</a>
    <span id='FLAG'>This link is accessible now!</span>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    /* This is the jQuery you need to accomplish what you want.
    | The rest was redundant and unnecessary.
    */
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#button-f").click(function(e) {
        $(".container").toggle();

      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning a z-index to #div-2?

You'll need to assign it a position to be able to give it a z-index. Try this:

```
#div-2 a{
width:13%;
height:auto;
padding:0.5em 2.3em;
display:block;
position:fixed;
font-weight:500;
font-size:1.09em;
text-align: center;
background-color: none;
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
z-index:2;
}

#div-1{
width:100%;
height:290px;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
position: relative;
z-index:1; 
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, that has something wrong the whole purpose is to make the anchor in a lower index, so when the container is toggled on/ viewed, the link won't be setting on top of the container. You made the link in index 2 higher than div 1 that has the container that makes the link floats on top already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what actually in your code but the js you provide look at the if section you have (##button-f) so we find an  error here and do we actually need this line ??like we also don't need the line 'container'.hide() in JS. Now you have to scroll for the 'a' certain height because yous set height for #div-1 which is not hidden. So that's amount of height you have to scroll. 
So What I change on your code 
1. cut the height of div-1 and place it to .container class. you dont provide the a:hover class so I add that to and remove some unnecessary css you have. If you have any other Question ask me in comment  [LIVE ON FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/u7sswczz/5/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#button-f").click(function() {
     $(".container").toggle();
   });
  });
```

```css
   button {
  width: 13%;
  height: auto;
}
#div-1{
width:100%;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
 }
.container {
   height:290px;
  display:none;
  border: 1px solid red;
   
}

#div-2 a {
  width: 13%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.5em 2.3em;
  display: block;
  positon:fixed;
  float:right;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.09em;
  text-align: center;

  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
 

}

#div-2 a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 
<body>
 <button id="button-f">
    button
 </button>
 <div id="div-1">
   <div class="container">tagasdgasdgasdgas</div>
 </div>

 <!-- other divs like 5 or 6 of 'em -->

 <div id="div-2">
   <a href='#'>This is a link</a>
 </div>
</body>
```